# Form: clear the filter combo if user remove the filter

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I created a **continuous form**, with a **combo box** in the header to allow user to easily apply one of the predefined filters.
If the user sets a filter and then clicks on the built-in `Filtered` rectangle at the bottom of the form to remove the filter, I'd like to empty the combo.
Since the `Filter` event does not fire in that case, and the `ApplyFilter` event runs BEFORE the `FilterOn` is modified, I cannot rely on them.

```
Private Sub Form_ApplyFilter(Cancel As Integer, ApplyType As Integer)
    Debug.Print Now, "Apply", Me.FilterOn, Me.Filter    'returns the OLD values :-(
End Sub
```

Any suggestion to solve this puzzle ? I think I carefully went through every form event, without success.
Otherwise I will have to hide the built in navigation buttons and I like to keep as much as possible of the built-in tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check the `ApplyType` in the `ApplyFilter` event (0 = filter cleared, 1 = filter applied or changed).

```
Private Sub Form_ApplyFilter(Cancel As Integer, ApplyType As Integer)
    If ApplyType = 0 Then
        'Clear that combobox
    End If
End Sub
```